# Change All User short date format in Windows 2008R2 using script

Tags: windows, date

I have hundreds of users in Windows 2008 R2. How can i change these user's Regional setting's short date format to DD-MM-YYYY using script ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could run a batch file, loaded in startup.cmd, with the necessary reg.exe command.  I used to send batch file fixes out to users on their desktop.

```
setlocal
set ykey=Control Panel\International
reg /add HKCU\%ykey% /v sShortDate /f /d "dd-mm-yy"
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update regional setting for all existing users and default value for newly created users in Control Panel (on Windows 7) with "Copy settings". This will overwrite all regional settings for users (not only short date format as requested above).

[image: Control Panel - Clock, Language, and Region - Change the date, time, or number formula - Administrative]

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using Group Policy Under User Config -> Preferences -> Control Panel Settings -> Regional Options.

More info here.. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754496.aspx

Comment: sorry, i can't find "Group Policy" in my windows 2008R2

Comment: If you don't know what Group Policy is and how to apply it to users, then I am not sure I can help you.  This question really is a professional system admin question.